# What is Moanegheh (المعانقه)?

Tags: greetings

I am aware that Moaneqah is a kind of greetings which is famous between Muslims and apparently has so Thawab, but I'd like to know what the circumstances of it are. (According to Quran or Hadith)

Answer (score 3):

Mo’aneqeh is considered as hugging or embracing each other (and putting the hands on the neck of each other). In fact, it is a sort of embracement when two Muslims visit each other. In other word, Muaniqah (المعانقه) is a kind of greeting (physical greeting) that when you visit each other, shake hands and hugging each other.

> *( کلینی، محمد بن یعقوب، الکافی، ج ‏2، ص 184، تهران، دار الکتب الإسلامیة، چاپ چهارم، 1407ق.)*

---

**Reference:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/ur21549)

Comment: so is this thing cultural or is it suggested by prophet Muhammad (pbuh)?

Comment: as my research, it has quoted from Shia Imams as an approved practice. So it could be religious more than cultural practice. / Many of Arabs do it as well. / Although it could be surveyed from non-religious aspect as well, as a nice act which can make a more powerful sincerity between Muslims brothers as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to a narration in [Sunan ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/33/46) it is something the Sahaba  asked our Messenger and he said "no" and told them "to shake hands" instead but this Hadith was qualified as da'if similar riwayat on the matter [here](http://islamport.com/w/krj/Web/128/1463.htm) (in Arabic).

One of those riwayat is from Imam [at-Trimidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/42/41) and was qualified as hassan!

So shaking hands is as far as i can tell the best to do when greeting each other. Even if we find other forms of greeting in our cultures. But it's according to some fatwa as you can read not forbidden!

And here's a [fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/49021) for the hugging for congratulation about 'id etc and here in case of [condolence](http://islamqa.info/ar/155368).